# Save font selection for plots in Paraview

Tags: paraview

I adjusted plotting fonts in a Paraview scene, saved as `.pvsm` file, and loaded it in a different Paraview version. The fonts changed. Can this be avoided? Also ticks (I set it to maximum of 3 ticks) settings are gone. Is `.pvsm` not the correct way to save a complex scene?

Comment: I think this (and all of the other questions you ask about Paraview) are better suited for the Paraview user forums.

Comment: So should I delete the question and restate my problem in the Paraview user forums?

Comment: You will probably have more luck that way.

Comment: Thank you, I will resort to the forum. Do you by any change know if Visit handles this better?

Comment: I believe so, but don't know for sure.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a shot @WolfgangBangerth